# How to Filter Records After GroupBy with LINQ + EF Core 6

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

Given this simple `Contract` entity and assuming that a customer can have many Contracts with different start dates and statuses.

```cs
public class Contract {
 [Key]
 int ContractId { get; set; }
 int CustomerId { get; set; } 
 string Status { get; set; }
 DateTime ContractStartDate { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to write a query to find that latest contract for each customer *and then* filter out certain statuses. I need to filter the status after finding the latest contract, to ensure I'm getting their current status.

| ContractID | CustomerID | ContractStartDate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | Active |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-31-05 | Inactive |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-01-03 | Active |
| 4 | 2 | 2022-31-07 | Inactive |

From the above data set, I would expect to get contracts 2 and 4 in the results. This is why I can't filter on status before grouping, because then the latest inactive row would be eliminated before I group them by customer to find the latest row.

I've tried something like, this:

```cs
var latestContracts = Query<Contract>()
    .GroupBy(grp => grp.CustomerId)
    .Select(s => s.OrderByDescending(s => s.ContractStartDate).First())
    .Where(w => w.Status == "Active");
```

but once I execute the query by calling `ToListAsync()`, etc. I get an error like this:

```
'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Customer>()
    .GroupBy(c => c.CustomerId)
    .Select(g => g
        .AsQueryable()
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.
   I CC ContractStartDate)
        .First())
    .Where(e0 => e0.AccountContractTermStatus == "Active")' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

If I remove the `Where` call, the query works fine and gives the intended newest results. I know that the support for translating LINQ to SQL is still not fully complete, even in EF Core 6, but this seems like something that should be possible. Am I missing something simple or is this just not yet doable via LINQ?

Happy to provide more context, as I've greatly simplified a production query into something I could share publicly.

Comment: Can you share Customer entity and relationships? and is CustomerId primary key?

Comment: @OkanKaradag I updated the model a bit. In this case, none of the properties are relationships, they are just reference numbers to ids in other systems. In fact, there isn't even a Customer entity in this system. The primary key is ContractId.

Comment: Grouping by CustomerId is unnecessary because CustomerId is primary key. you can try removed?

Comment: Doh. In my haste to edit, I mis-typed. ContractId is the key. There can be many contracts for each customer. That is why I am grouping by customer.

Comment: *"I need to filter the status after finding the latest contract, to ensure I'm getting their current status."* -- if you filter out status anyways, why not just call `where` and then `group`-`select\order\first` ?? Provide a sample data input (preferably in format `var c1=new Contract(){ContractId  = 1, CustomerId = 11....}`) and the desired output from the data you provided. i.e. "i should see this output"

Comment: @T.S. I added a sample data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following emulation of query which EF Core cannot translate. It is almost direct translation what EF Core should do in your case.

```cs
var dataQuery = Query<Contract>();

var latestContracts = 
    from d in dataQuery.Select(d => new { d.CustomerId }).Distinct()
    from c in dataQuery
        .Where(c => d.CustomerId == c.CustomerId)
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.ContractStartDate)
        .Take(1)
    where c.Status == "Active"
    select c;
```

Or using Method Chain syntax:

```cs
var dataQuery = Query<Contract>();

var latestContracts = dataQuery
    .Select(d => new { d.CustomerId })
    .Distinct()
    .SelectMany(d => dataQuery
        .Where(c => d.CustomerId == c.CustomerId)
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.ContractStartDate)
        .Take(1))
    .Where(c => c.Status == "Active");
```

Comment: This also throws an exception that the LINQ expression cannot be translated.

Comment: @BrianM. I have rewritten query.

Comment: This seems to work and puts me on the right track to move forward. Is it possible to write this solely using method syntax? Our code base prefers that, but if it's not possible, I will live with it.

Comment: @BrianM. I have added this option, but I personally do not prefer to use Method Chain syntax when there is joins or SelectMany.

Comment: i have done the same thing in ef core 7 for the same problem, but it still throws error. 
The LINQ expression 'queryContext' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information
@SvyatoslavDanyliv, can you help please

Comment: @thanzeel, create new question and show your query.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, here i created the quesstion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75100594/ef-core-7-apply-where-after-select-throws-error