# EF Core 7 - Apply where() after Select throws error

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-entities, ef-core-7.0

I have a query which does a group by and then selects and then tries to apply a `Where()` filter on the select. but it throws error after I apply the filter for OpenBalance on the latest selected row

```cs
var billTable = _context.Set<Bill>();

var billQuery = billTable
    .Where(w => w.PaymentStatus != PaymentStatus.None)
    .Where(w => w.OperationalStatus == OperationalBillStatus.Approved &&
    (
        w.FinancialStatus == FinancialBillStatus.Pending ||
        w.FinancialStatus == FinancialBillStatus.Approved ||
        w.FinancialStatus == FinancialBillStatus.OnHold ||
        w.FinancialStatus == FinancialBillStatus.PartiallyApproved
    ))
    .AsQueryable();

billQuery = ApplyOptionalFilters(filter, billQuery);

var temporalBillQuery = billTable
    .TemporalAll()
    .Where(w => billQuery.Select(s => s.Id).Contains(w.Id))
    .Where(w => w.UpdatedOn!.Value.Date <= filter.AsAtDate.Date)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.DueDate!.Value)
    .AsQueryable();

var billAsAtDateQuery = temporalBillQuery.Select(s => new
{
    UpdatedOn = s.UpdatedOn,
    BillId = s.Id,
    Aging = (filter.AsAtDate.Date - s.DueDate!.Value.Date).Days,
    s.InvoiceNumber,
    s.InvoiceDate,
    DueDate = s.DueDate,
    OpenBalance = (s.LineItemTotal + s.VATAmount - s.TotalPaidAmount)
}).AsQueryable();

var finalQuery = billAsAtDateQuery
    .GroupBy(g => g.BillId)
    .Select(s => s.OrderByDescending(o => o.UpdatedOn).First())
    .AsQueryable();

if (filter.OpenBalanceMinAmount.HasValue)
{
    finalQuery = finalQuery.Where(w => w.OpenBalance >= filter.OpenBalanceMinAmount.Value);
}
```

the error is thrown after this query

```cs
var finalQuery = billAsAtDateQuery
    .GroupBy(g => g.BillId)
    .Select(s => s.OrderByDescending(o => o.UpdatedOn).First())
    .AsQueryable();

if (filter.OpenBalanceMinAmount.HasValue)
{
    finalQuery = finalQuery.Where(w => w.OpenBalance >= filter.OpenBalanceMinAmount.Value);
}
```

Error msg is

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Bill>().TemporalAll()
    .Where(b => __ef_filter__CompanyIds_0.Contains(b.CompanyId) && b.IsDeleted == False)
    .Where(b => DbSet<Bill>()
        .Where(b0 => __ef_filter__CompanyIds_0.Contains(b0.CompanyId) && b0.IsDeleted == False)
        .Where(b0 => (int)b0.PaymentStatus != 1)
        .Where(b0 => (int)b0.OperationalStatus == 3 && (int)b0.FinancialStatus == 2 || (int)b0.FinancialStatus == 4 ||
(int)b0.FinancialStatus == 5 || (int)b0.FinancialStatus == 6)
        .Select(b0 => b0.Id)
        .Any(p => object.Equals(
            objA: (object)p, 
            objB: (object)b.Id)))
    .Where(b => b.UpdatedOn.Value.Date <= __filter_AsAtDate_Date_0)
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.DueDate.Value)
    .GroupBy(b => b.Id)
    .Select(g => g
        .AsQueryable()
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.UpdatedOn)
        .Select(e => new { 
            UpdatedOn = e.UpdatedOn, 
            BillId = e.Id, 
            Aging = (__filter_AsAtDate_Date_0 - e.DueDate.Value.Date).Days, 
            InvoiceNumber = e.InvoiceNumber, 
            InvoiceDate = e.InvoiceDate, 
            DueDate = e.DueDate, 
            OpenBalance = e.LineItemTotal + e.VATAmount - e.TotalPaidAmount
         })
        .First())
    .Where(e0 => e0.OpenBalance >= __filter_OpenBalanceMinAmount_Value_1)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information. 

 Stack Trace:
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.<VisitMethodCall>g__CheckTranslated|15_0(ShapedQueryExpressiontranslated, <>c__DisplayClass15_0&)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpressionmethodCallExpression)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpressionmethodCallExpression)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expressionquery)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expressionquery, Boolean async)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabasedatabase, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](ObjectcacheKey, Func`1 compiler)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expressionquery, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expressionexpression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationTokencancellationToken)    
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
at VPMS.Persistence.Repositories.Reports.VendorReportRepository.APAgingDetailReport(Paginatorpaginator, APAgingReportFilter filter, CancellationToken token) in C:\Projects\Legacy HealthCare - Vendor Payment Management System\VPMS\VPMS.Persistence\Repositories\Reports\VendorReportRepository.cs:line 565    
at VPMS.Application.Reports.Services.ReportService.APAgingDetailReport(Paginatorpaginator, APAgingReportFilter filter, CancellationToken token) in C:\Projects\Legacy HealthCare - Vendor Payment Management System\VPMS\VPMS.Application\Reports\Services\ReportService.cs:line 59
at VPMS.Api.Controllers.V1.Reports.PaymentReportsController.APAgingDetailReport(Paginatorpaginator, APAgingReportFilter filter, CancellationToken token) in C:\Projects\Legacy HealthCare - Vendor Payment Management System\VPMS\VPMS.Api\Controllers\V1\Reports\PaymentReportsController.cs:line 48    
at lambda_method240(Closure, Object)    
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContextactionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object ] arguments)    
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvokerinvoker)    
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvokerinvoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)    
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealedcontext)    
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync() 
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---    
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvokerinvoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)    
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvokerinvoker)    
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvokerinvoker)    
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpointendpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContextcontext)    
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContextcontext)    
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContexthttpContext)    
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContexthttpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    
at VPMS.Api.Middleware.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContextcontext) in C:\Projects\Legacy HealthCare - Vendor Payment Management System\VPMS\VPMS.Api\Middleware\ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs:line 25
```

Comment: Why you put `AsQueryable()` after each query?

Comment: Yeah, you should just make the query the correct type in the first place, which would be `IQueryable<Bill> billQuery = billTable...`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, i used AsQuery() to return an IQueryyable, is it wrong to apply?

Comment: Unnecessary after `Select`, `Where`, `GroupBy`, etc.

Comment: Try comment out `Aging` property it can be non translatable.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv ,yes, it worked, after i commented the Aging. This will be the answer. If possible can you help me to get the Aging at the sql level rather than taking in in memory of the API server please

Comment: Use [DateDiffDay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62582934/10646316)

Comment: also, if possible, @SvyatoslavDanyliv, can you explain why Aging coursed the problem if you can please

Comment: Because EF Core still cannot translate such construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `finalQuery` with this one:

```cs
var finalQuery = 
    from d in billAsAtDateQuery.Select(d => new { g.BillId }).Distinct()
    from b in billAsAtDateQuery
        .Where(b => b.BillId == d.BillId)
        .OrderByDescending(o => o.UpdatedOn)
        .Take(1)
    select b;
```

Comment: i tried with the above query and now i get a different error message 

The LINQ expression 'queryContext' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.